# GraphQL disable input validation, add custom error

Tags: java, validation, graphql, error-suppression

Trying to disable explicit message on input validation errors.
When I request a field that does not exist (i.e age) i get:

```
{
"data": null,
"errors": [{
        "path": null,
        "locations": [
            {
                "line": 1,
                "column": 129,
                "sourceName": null
            }
        ],
        "message": "Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'age' in type 'Patient' is undefined @ 'path/age'"
    }]}
```

I want to override the error to show a custom error message:

```
    {
"data": null,
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "invalid fields"
    }
]}
```

sample of my schema with custom SystemError (does not work):

```
type Patient {
  id: Int!
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
}

type Query {
  patient(id: Int!): Patient
  errors: [SystemError]
}

type SystemError {
  id: Int!
  message: String
}

schema {
  query: Query
}
```

Comment: and the server is? use middleware

Comment: @xadm what do you need to know about the server?
abd which middleware do you refer to?

Comment: problem is implementation (server) related, not general graphql

Comment: @xadm any idea what should i look for?

Comment: your server (still unknown) middleware (if exists/is supported)

Comment: @xadm using aws appsync with vtl

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a middleware, f.e. `middy` (some googled appsync middleware), https://github.com/bboure/middy-appsync#error-handling

To limit error info you can try (not tested) to use something like this:

```
const doStuff = (event, context, callback) => {
  if( context.result && context.result.errorMessage ) {
    callback(new GraphQlError('Error'));
  } else {
    callback(null, context.result.data);
  }
};
```